# Gridview footer data format string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to format a gridview column footer value as currency. I'v set the DataFormatString of the BoundField to {0:c} but this doesn't seem to affect the footer. Do I have to do it in the RowDataBound event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in a way similar to this...

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    double dVal = 0.0;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        dVal += Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = dVal.ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set HtmlEncode="False" on the footer?

Edit: this has been a known issue for a while.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kludge. (sp?)

But sometimes in the face of known issues, you've gotta kludge. (sp?)

```
private static string FormatByGridView(object value, string DataFormatString)
{
    GridView grid = new GridView();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("value", value.GetType());
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row["value"] = value;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    grid.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { DataField = "value", DataFormatString = DataFormatString });
    grid.DataSource = table;
    grid.DataBind();
    return grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
   e.Row.Cells[2].Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,###.00}", total2013);
   e.Row.Cells[3].Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,###.00}", total2014);
}
```